# If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then the power series $\sum a_n z^n$ has a positive radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then the power series $\sum a_n z^n$ has a positive radius of convergence. Prove or disprove. I am unable to connect the convergence of the series and the corresponding power series. Help please.

Comment: The result  is true even if $a_n$ is just bounded which is much weaker than the hypothesis here (with radius convergence at least  $1$); when a series converges the generic term goes to zero so radius is at least $1$

Comment: I would guess this was an exercise intended to reinforce your understanding of the *radius of convergence*.  First step is to recognize that the given convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies the convergence of the power series for a particular value of $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$.  This is a power series centered at $z = 0$, at which point it converges (to $a_0$).  The interval of convergence is symmetric about the center.  Notice that $f(1) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, which is given to converge, so the radius of convergence is at least $1$.  Since all radii greater than or equal to $1$ are positive, $f$ has a positive radius of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

You might know that, by Abel's lemma,

$$\sum a_nz_0^n\text{ converges } \implies R\ge |z_0|$$
So,

$$\sum a_n \text{ converges } \implies$$
$$z_0=1\implies R\ge 1$$